Simulink/Matlab, what is the name of this block?
Here is a image
I highlighted it with a red border. I'm counting on your help, because I couldn't find it in MATLAB's documentation myself. The author in the recording also doesn't mention what this block is called, and I've never used it myself.

A quick search reveals it can be a block called Memory, which introduces a delay.

